# How to Delete Duplicate Values in a HashSet

Tags: java, sql, hashset

I'm creating a HashSet of strings grabbed from a table in SQL database. So far it is working and the results are printing correctly.

However, I am curious as to how I can remove duplicate strings from my HashSet before I print it out.

```
List<String> resultsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
resultsArray.add(results.getString("SCINAME"));

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(resultsArray);
System.out.println(set);
```

Is there a quick solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Eh? A `HashSet` cannot contain duplicates. By putting your `String`s into a `Set` your are already removing duplicates.

Comment: HashSet consideres duplicate those objects whose hashCodes are equal and by equals method they are equal. To find out more of HashSet please cover my tutorial [internal life of HashSet](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashset-in-java.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, you are missing something here. In the question you mentioned HashMap and in the implementation you have HashSet.

Remember, **HashSet implements the Set interface**, which does not contain duplicates.

So, when you implement `objectOfHashSet.add(duplicates);` it will **return false.**

Comment: You are correct. It turns out I was grabbing some values with extra characters from the database, that looked similar. Thank you. I'll accept your answer as soon as I am able to.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi I would appreciate if you could elaborate a little on your comment, with the similarity for HashSet and HashMap. Tx

Comment: Open source code of java.util.HashSet or read my post [Internal life of HashSet](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashset-in-java.html).